# Does a static library contain a CRT when you specificy /MT, or is that only for DLLs?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

When a static library is created and in the Visual Studio options you suggest that it must use a static library (/MT). Does that mean that the static library you're currently compiling has the CRT linked into it?

Then for example if I use this static library with another static library that did the same thing, will this result in multiple CRTs when I ultimately make a DLL out of these two static libraries and more code I compile?

Or is the /MT option basically only for a DLL? Of course it must be that all components should specify the same options, but it would seem silly if you say statically link a CRT and it now gets included multiple times.

Comment: Static library is not linked at all, with CRT or otherwise. It's just a collection of .obj files. Any dependencies are resolved when an executable is linked with it.

Comment: No, the library has a linker instruction in it that says that it eventually needs to be linked to the static CRT library.  It is equivalent to #pragma comment(lib, "libcmt.lib").  If that doesn't happen because the consuming project overrode it with /nodefaultlib then you're in unspecified behavior territory.